# What does iResolution mean in a shader?

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I am new to GLSL. I find there is a variable `iResolution` in every demo https://www.shadertoy.com/new. What does it mean?

If I want to pass this variable to the shader, what do I need do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can see the definition if you expand the "Shader Inputs" section above the code:

[image]

The description pretty much says it all. It's the size of the window/viewport in pixels. In the example, `gl_FragCoord`, which is the position in pixels of the fragment, is divided by this size to obtain the relative position of the fragment within the viewport.

You would set this like any other uniform variable:

```
GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "iResolution");
glUniform2f(loc, width, height);
```

where `width` and `height` are the size of your window/viewport. It's odd that this is defined as a `vec3`, since only the `x` and `y` values are useful.

Comment: Not exactly sure but looks like shaders I was porting from Shadertoy to pixijs was expecting iResolution to be [0;1]

Comment: For anyone else coming to this answer via Google trying to find out WHY it's a vec3: the third component is the [pixel aspect ratio](https://twitter.com/iquilezles/status/633113177568313344), which is 1.0 if your display has square pixels.